# idea git and terminal git

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a question , Why I made the idea of the changes in the MAC comes with the terminal can not use git status can be seen, but in the idea of the terminal can see！

As shown below：

idea‘s terminal： [image]

mac’s terminal： [image]

can anyone help me ? thanks !

Comment: Wild guess, but do you have a .gitignore file?

Comment: Go to File > Synchronize in Idea, it's solved problems like this for me a few times.

Comment: thanks ! I went to File -> Synchronize in idea ,  solved this problems